# Call flow of Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

It is a very naive question but I just started with Veins, and unable to understand the call flow of Veins. When we start .ini file which file is called first? as in the case of c++ program main() is called first. What is the starting point of vein app? I hope someone can guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to learn Veins without learning OMNeT++ first, you are jumping in at the deep end. For OMNeT++, excellent tutorials, videos, and a comprehensive user manual are available on the [documentation pages on the OMNeT++ website](http://www.omnetpp.org/documentation).

If you are in much of a hurry, I can highly recommend the 10-minute introduction linked from there, as well as the [TicToc tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial). Both address your questions in much more detail as can be done in a short StackOverflow answer alone.

Still, to give a brief answer specifically to your questions: the .ini file specifies which network to instantiate and how to parameterize the network. The network (essentially an instance of a compound module) defines which constituent modules to instantiate. These modules form a tree, each leaf of which is a simple module. Each simple module is an instance of a C++ class. At initialization of the network, the `initialize` methods of each of these C++ classes will be called in (essentially) random order. These method calls can be thought of as the starting points of your simulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did go through TicToc tutorial, but in veins, I am still not able to understand how cars are generated? There is no structure defined in .ned file.